# How to get all instances variables in ruby class?

Tags: ruby, class, variables, instance

I have a ruby class, and in one of the methods, it calls an external function, and pass in all instance variables, and continue with the return value. Here is the code:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :name1
  attr_accessor :name2
  ...
  attr_accessor :namen


  def inner_func():
    all_vars = ???? # how to collect all my instance variables into a dict/Hash?
    res = out_func(all_vars)
    do_more_stuff(res)
  end
end
```

The problem is the instance variables might vary in subclasses. I can't refer them as their names. So, is there a way to do this? Or Am I thinking in a wrong way?

Comment: This is begging the question 'why'. It might be reasonable depending on your use case, but it's highly unlikely. Instance variables are implementation details, and passing those around does not sound good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `instance_variables` to collect them in an Array. You will get all initialized instance variables.

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :name1
  attr_accessor :name2
  ...
  attr_accessor :namen


  def inner_func():
    all_vars = instance_variables
    res = out_func(all_vars)
    do_more_stuff(res)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of all accessors as you create them:

```
class Receiver
  def work(arguments)
    puts "Working with #{arguments.inspect}"
  end
end

class MyClass
  def self.attr_accessor(*arguments)
    super
    @__attribute_names__ ||= []
    @__attribute_names__ += arguments
  end

  def self.attribute_names
    @__attribute_names__
  end

  def self.inherited(base)
    parent = self
    base.class_eval do
      @__attribute_names__ = parent.attribute_names
    end
  end

  def attributes
    self.class.attribute_names.each_with_object({}) do |attribute_name, result|
      result[attribute_name] = public_send(attribute_name)
    end
  end

  def work
    Receiver.new.work(attributes)
  end

  attr_accessor :foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end

class MySubclass < MyClass
  attr_accessor :baz
end
```

Usage

```
my_class = MyClass.new
my_class.foo = 123
my_class.bar = 234
my_class.work
# Working with {:foo=>123, :bar=>234}

my_subclass = MySubclass.new
my_subclass.foo = 123
my_subclass.bar = 234
my_subclass.baz = 345
my_subclass.work
# Working with {:foo=>123, :bar=>234, :baz=>345}
```